# Not retriving the data from csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql

I wanted to import the csv file into the mysql. I am using this following code:

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'D:\20507.csv' 
INTO TABLE rohit1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

But it is not working; it shows only first column record?
Help me to out.

Comment: Maybe tell us a bit more about your `rohit1` table and your csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'D:/20507.csv' INTO TABLE rohit1 FIELDS TERMINATED
BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```